# installation of jekyll failed - Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to install jekyll on a 32 bit windows 7 PC . I downloaded ruby installer-32 bit and  32 bit devkit and extracted un ruby install folder.i got some ssh error which i resolved by temporarily switching to http instead of https and then updated gems as well as installed bundler using

```
 gem install bundler
```

however gem install jekyll gives following error

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150109-5804-1k3wbva.rb extconf.rb
No such file or directory - C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150109-5804-1k
3wbva.rb extconf.rb 2>&1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fast-stemm
er-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/fas
t-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Well, 32 bit machine. It's time to give a try to a Linux distribution like Ubuntu ! This will definitely save you a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same thing on 3 systems and found out that installing ruby gems fixed the issue .. so for anyone coming back at this question , this is how you install jekyll on a windows pc:

1.download and install ruby.

2.download devkit extract in to a folder(preferably inside ruby installation dir) and type in cmd window while in your devkit dir :

```
 ruby dk.rb init
 ruby dk.rb install
```

3.download and install gems by

```
 ruby setup.rb
```

4. finally :

```
 gem install bundler 
 gem install jekyll
```

*bundler is a jekyll dependency

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Ruby [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) to fix the error you're seeing. Any sane Ruby install has the ability to build stuff on the fly.

I would start with Julian Thilo's awesome instructions for installing Jekyll on Windows:

[Run Jekyll on Windows](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/)

If you are installing Ruby only for the purpose of running Jekyll, [PortableJekyll](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll) will give you a full working Jekyll install in < 5 minutes.

Happy Jekylling...

Comment: I have devkit installed definitely. But gem install Jekyll fails... However portable Jekyll seems like good option..

Comment: I am a Java & perl developer.. And dabble in front end / python so yes not much interested in ruby

Comment: Re devkit -- I had to follow Thilo's instructions to the letter but eventually did get it working. There are specific versions you'll want for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Windows 10 after installing `Ruby+Devkit 2.5.X (x64)` with the Windows installer.

The reason was that I changed the default path in the installer and had spaces in the path name. Apparently some make scripts do not like that.

Reinstalling to a path without any spaces fixed the issue.

Also see [this related issue on github](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7587).

Answer (score 0):

I failed to install "gem install jekyll bundler" when ruby was installed in "c:\program files\Ruby26-x64". After I reinstalled ruby on c:\Ruby26-x64 everything went ok. Seems like installation fails to parse path with blank